# Pointer generalization of index

Tags: c++

Referencing with indexes compared to referencing with pointers has several advantages, e.g. indexes often survive array reallocation. But pointers/references are often more convenient to use than indexes. In the C++ STL library, the iterators were designed as generalizations of the pointer and now I wonder whether we could do something similar for indexes: little classes that carry the index as local data, but behave like (convenient) pointers. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <compare>

template<class T, class I, T** ppdata>
struct index_ptr_T
{
    explicit index_ptr_T(I index = 0)
        : m_index(index)
    {}
    index_ptr_T(T* p)
        : m_index(p - *ppdata)
    {}
    T* operator->() const
    {
        return *ppdata + m_index;
    }
    T& operator*() const
    {
        return *(*ppdata + m_index);
    }
    friend auto operator<=>(const index_ptr_T<T, I, ppdata>&, const index_ptr_T<T, I, ppdata>&) = default;
    I m_index;
};

struct s_t // a test class
{
    inline static s_t* pdata{};
    using index_ptr_t = index_ptr_T<s_t, short, &pdata>;
    int m_i;
    index_ptr_t m_next;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<s_t> data(2);
    s_t::pdata = &data[0];
    s_t::index_ptr_t pa = &data[0];
    *pa = { 10, 0 };
    s_t::index_ptr_t pb = &data[1];
    pb->m_next = pa;
    std::cout << pb->m_next->m_i << std::endl;
    data.reserve(data.capacity() + 1);
    s_t::pdata = &data[0];
    std::cout << pb->m_next->m_i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(s_t::index_ptr_t) = " << sizeof(s_t::index_ptr_t) << std::endl;
}
```

Does something like this already exist in library form? Or did someone already publish about it? I googled, but couldn’t find what I was looking for. The `index_ptr_T` class above is quite incomplete, many operators are missing. I would like to use a proven library.

Note 1: I've !!EDITED!! above example to clarify a little bit more the intended use.

Note 2: `s_t::pdata = &data[0]` must also be done whenever the data is realocated/moved. E.g. when the data is in a vector after elements have been added.

Comment: I don't understand what you are missing from iterators. For containers that have an index, the index is modeled by the iterator.

Comment: What's the benefits of using your class over using a pointer?

Comment: A pointer wouldn't update if the array was reallocated. I'd ask what the benefit of using this class over an index is instead.

Comment: Suppose I have many (different) objects, stored in vectors, referring to each other, e.g. like in graphs. Now I add one object to the vector. @largest_prime_is_463035818: then all my iterators invalidate. Now I only must update the (global) base pointer with parray = array, and all my indexes work again like pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Same remark as above, but then all my pointers invalidate (i.s.o. iterators)

Comment: @Andy Newman Suppose struct s_t had a member m_next that refers to another s_t object. For index (1) the member would be int m_next; for the ptr generalization (2) it would be array_index_ptr m_next. Now compare getting m_i from next of s_t s: 1) array[s.m_next].m_i 2) s.m_next->m_i. To me, the latter is more convenient, additionally you cannot put the index in the wrong array.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed design is rather limited, thanks to templating on the array object. A slightly more reasonable design would look like this:

```cpp
template<typename ContainerType, typename IndexType>
struct index_ptr_T
{
    index_ptr_T(ContainerType & container, IndexType index)
        : m_container(container), m_index(index) {}

    auto* operator->()
    {
        return &m_container[m_index];
    }
    auto & operator*()
    {
        return m_container[m_index];
    }

    ContainerType & m_container;
    IndexType m_index;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    int i = 1;
    index_ptr_T p{v, i};
    v.reserve(v.capacity() + 1);
    std::cout << *p;
}
```

Or, more succinctly, with no separate utility:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    int i = 1;
    auto p = [&v, i]() -> auto & { return v[i]; };
    v.reserve(v.capacity() + 1);
    std::cout << p();
}
```

I'm not aware of anything like this in existing frameworks. As you can see, there's just not much *in* the concept. It's just a bound indexing operation. Making it into a utility would make code harder to read, without making it easier to write.

Comment: This solution also saves the previous required parray = array after adding data to e.g. a vector. On the other side, it requires an additional reference to the container in every generalized ptr. On a 64bit platform this triples the size.

Comment: The solution with “no separate utility” provides access to an element, but it does not behave like a pointer. The intended use is for (different) objects referring to each other, e.g. classes having members like array_index_ptr m_next, compared to s_t* m_next.

Comment: Any approach which is separately dereferenceable must either refer directly to a container through a member, or be bound to it as a compile-time constant. The latter is not practical.

Comment: I've edited the original question so that it clarifies a bit more the intended use. See also the 'header only' solution for the compile-time constant: pdata

Comment: That still requires the compile-time constant. I think the best approach for you might be to  start using your proposed class, not in test code but in a nontrivial practical application, with multiple containers, encapsulated in other objects. I suspect that'll help you understand the limitations.